# How to avoid parent sending event to child in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend

I have the following situation:

- I have a component library with modal component. The modal already have action button implemented and when user click, it emits a click event.
- This modal can be used to render one of couple of component inside of it.
- I want to trigger an action related to the state of the child when user clicks on the action button
- The modal also has a skip button that will switch the component inside of it

[Modal graphic description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pfGN0.png)

What i'm doing now is this:
I have a component that accepts a key as a props, and from a pre-defined map, i will know the component i want to render (using React.lazy()), modal title, and action button text.
It works, but this way i have to use my child's function when the action button is clicked (for example with using ref) but i want to avoid this, since it's not the react way.

```
export function MyModal(props: MyModalProps) {
  const {onClose, isOpen, key} = props;
  // custom hook that gives me the details for the render (including the component with React.lazy)
  const {
    title, subtitle, Component, actionText, changeKey, nextKey
  } = useModalRenderDetails(key);
  const handleModalHide = (event) => {
    onClose();
  };

  return (
    <Modal
      modalTitle={title}
      modalSubtitle={subtitle}
      mainActionLabel={actionText}
      secondaryActionLabel={'Skip'}
      open={isOpen}
      onHide={event => handleModalHide(event)}
      onMainAction={childHandlerFunctionFromRef}
      onSecondaryAction={() => changeKey(nextKey)}
    >
      <React.Suspense fallback={<div>LOADING</div>}>
        <Component/>
      </React.Suspense>
    </Modal>
  );
}
```

can anyone provide a better solution for this situation?
Feel free to suggest design changes if needed

Comment: Please reformulate your question into something that is unambiguously and definitively answerable.  If an answer to your question can be "yes" or "no" it is probably too vague.  Asking for code reviews or design suggestions is beyond the scope of this site.

Comment: You are saying "design suggestions is beyond the scope of this site" because i mentioned the word "design"? 

Im seeing a lot of questions (and answers) with design suggestions
@possum

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a good usage of a `context`.

### Context:

Consider placing the code below in a separate file and exporting only necessary items.

First of all, define a context:

```
const ConnectionContext = createContext();
```

Then create a custom provider to wrap the functions you need

```
const ConnectionContextProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const action = useRef(null);

  const setAction = (action) => {
    action.current = action;
  }

  const removeAction = () => {
    action.current = null;
  }

  const dispatchAction = () => {
    action.current && action.current()
  }

  return (
    <ConnectionContext.Provider
      value={{
        setAction,
        removeAction,
        dispatchAction,
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </ConnectionContext.Provider>
  );
}
```

Then wrap the `useContext` (this step is optional)

```
const useConnectionContext = () => {
  const context = useContext(context);
  return context;
}
```

### Usage:

In the parent:

```
const MyModal = () => {
  const { dispatchAction } = useConnectionContext()
  // ...
  return (
    <Modal
      // ...
      onMainAction={dispatchAction}
    >
      // ...
    </Modal>
   )
}
```

In the child:

```
const Child = () => {
  const { setAction, removeAction } = useConnectionContext()

  useEffect(() => {
    setAction(() => {
      // the action you want to run
    })
    return () => removeAction()
  }, [])
}
```

Have in mind that all code in this answer is untested.